# Unusual System CPU usage at 10%

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

Task manager view
[image: Task manager view]

Process explorer view

[image: Process explorer view]

Process thread details

[image: Processor Info]

I have noticed over the past weeks, that my system thread in task manager is always around 10%, which wasn't the case before.

Exploring the task in Process explorer showed something to do with 
`ntoskrnl.exe!DbgSetDebugFilterState+0x20` but searching on google for those things didn't come up with answers.

I don't know if some OS expert can give advice on what happened here?

---

**UPDATE**
I went through the linked question and was able to install the Windows SDK for analyzing the performance, but even with the logs and analysis I couldn't find a specific culprit.

[image: WPA result]

Eventually I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the page file first, and then setting custom size from 9GB to 100MB - 1GB. 
This seems to have eliminated the kernel pagefile manipulation that would keep going on. I hope this is the correct culprit.

Comment: system process in task manager

Comment: the core kernel process. the system image path ...etc. show's nothing.

Comment: not that i'm aware of. the only applications i'm using right now are: chrome, word, notepad++, skype, freemeter

Comment: If it’s the kernel, I’d have to say it’s a misbehaving driver. Could be a rootkit/malware or some recently added hardware/driver.

Comment: @Appleoddity Sorry, but drivers have very little to do with MiWalkPageTableRecursively, or with the balance set manager thread in general.

Comment: _"I hope this is the correct culprit."_ Sorry, but it isn't. You just changed the scenario slightly.  @magicandre1981: It looks like the same symptom, but not when you look more closely. See my answer to the OP's new question. https://superuser.com/questions/1360097/how-to-control-cpu-usage-of-ntoskrnl-exemiwalkpagetablesrecursively